# Combine multiple database with different queries in 1 report ( bar chart)

Tags: pentaho

I need to create a report using Pentaho User Console. I want to view my report in bar chart. In that report I need to include multiple query from different database and then the result in 1 chart. For example I have 3 database: Car, House, employee. I also have 3 query: quantity of car for each type, quantity of available house, total no of employee for each department. 3 different database and 3 different query but I want to show all 3 result in 1 chart. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You know about schema creation?
Go through on google how to create schema, what is fact table, what is dimension table..

And you can use pentaho schema workbench. It is used for your kind of purpose only.

and after creating schema in pentaho schema workbench you can publish that schema in pentaho BI server and you can view it in bar chart over their, and you can do analysis and drill-up , drill-down, slicing, dicing kinds of operations as well.

Comment: Actually, can I connect to multiple database using this schema workbench? I want to create a report by combining more than 1 database but it seems this schema can't do that. It only can connect to 1 database at a time

Comment: yOU WANT to connect multiple database? I don't know your requirement but it is strange..
No you can-not connect multiple database, you can connect with multiple table..

Comment: Yes, I need to connect to multiple database and combine it in 1 report. Yes it is strange but that is what my client want and I have to find the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kettle transformation as a data source for Pentaho report. Within the transformation it's perfectly fine to query 3 different DBs and prepare the result data set.